# Convert timestamp string to long in java

Tags: java, string, numberformatexception

I have to fetch time stamp from DB and retrieve only time and compare two time.

//below are the string values

```
 String st1 = "2015-07-24T09:39:14.000Z";      
 String st2 = "2015-07-24T09:45:44.000Z";
```

//retrieving only time **09:39:14**

```
 String s = st1.substring(st1.indexOf("T") + 1, st1.indexOf(".0"));
```

//string to Long.

```
 Long time = Long.parseLong(s);

 Long tim1=Long.valueOf(s).longValue();
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: So essentially you want to do 'Long.toString("09:39:14")'. That won't work cause it's not a number. What long value are you expecting? Is it the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT?

Comment: HI @user2341963 , I am expecting this :09:39:14 . so that i can compare both the time

Comment: @thanga By the way, if you are fetching the date-time values from a database you should be receiving date-time objects, probably java.sql.Timestamp, rather than Strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is by using SimpleDateFormat (May not be the best compare to JODA Time)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String st1 = "2015-07-24T09:39:14.000Z";
        String st2 = "2015-07-24T09:45:44.000Z";

        String time1 = st1.substring(st1.indexOf("T") + 1, st1.indexOf(".0"));
        String time2 = st2.substring(st2.indexOf("T") + 1, st2.indexOf(".0"));

        Date dateTime1 = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").parse(time1);
        Date dateTime2 = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").parse(time2);

        System.out.println(dateTime1.after(dateTime2));

    }
```

Answer (score 17):

Try this way, **Example code:**

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts2 = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2015-07-24T09:45:44.000Z");
long tsTime2 = ts2.getTime();
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? The [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) says the string must be in JDBC format (SQL format). That means a SPACE between the date portion and time-of-day portion. The `T` in the middle is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

Comment: @BasilBourque Yeah, the "T" causes an IllegalArgumentException.  And then the "Z" causes a NumberFormatException.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution would be to use Java 8's Date/Time API

```
LocalDateTime from = LocalDateTime.parse("2015-07-24T09:39:14.000Z", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
LocalDateTime to = LocalDateTime.parse("2015-07-24T09:45:44.000Z", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
System.out.println(from + " - " + to);

LocalTime fromTime = from.toLocalTime();
LocalTime toTime = to.toLocalTime();

System.out.println(fromTime + " - " + toTime);

System.out.println(fromTime + " before " + toTime + " = " + fromTime.isBefore(toTime));
System.out.println(fromTime + " after " + toTime + " = " + fromTime.isAfter(toTime));
System.out.println(fromTime + " equals " + toTime + " = " + fromTime.equals(toTime));
System.out.println(fromTime + " compareTo " + toTime + " = " + fromTime.compareTo(toTime));
```

Which outputs

```
2015-07-24T09:39:14 - 2015-07-24T09:45:44
09:39:14 - 09:45:44
09:39:14 before 09:45:44 = true
09:39:14 after 09:45:44 = false
09:39:14 equals 09:45:44 = false
09:39:14 compareTo 09:45:44 = -1
```

If you're not using Java 8, then use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) which works in similar way

## Joda-Time example...

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime;
import org.joda.time.LocalTime;
import org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat;

public class JodaTimeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateTime from = LocalDateTime.parse("2015-07-24T09:39:14.000Z", ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime());
        LocalDateTime to = LocalDateTime.parse("2015-07-24T09:45:44.000Z", ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime());

        LocalTime fromTime = from.toLocalTime();
        LocalTime toTime = to.toLocalTime();

        System.out.println(fromTime + " - " + toTime);

        System.out.println(fromTime + " before " + toTime + " = " + fromTime.isBefore(toTime));
        System.out.println(fromTime + " after " + toTime + " = " + fromTime.isAfter(toTime));
        System.out.println(fromTime + " equals " + toTime + " = " + fromTime.equals(toTime));
        System.out.println(fromTime + " compareTo " + toTime + " = " + fromTime.compareTo(toTime));
    }

}
```

Which outputs

```
09:39:14.000 - 09:45:44.000
09:39:14.000 before 09:45:44.000 = true
09:39:14.000 after 09:45:44.000 = false
09:39:14.000 equals 09:45:44.000 = false
09:39:14.000 compareTo 09:45:44.000 = -1
```

Comment: Hi @MadProgrammer ,  DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME); getting error here..imported joda-time. thanks

Comment: @thanga Joda-Time example added

Comment: @thanga Glad it could help

Comment: OP wanted to convert timestamps to longs, but none of your outputs show any longs.

Comment: @pacoverflow *"retrieve only time and compare two time"* - I skipped the title and went to the core issue - time comparison should NEVER be done by comparing `long` values, it should be done through appropriate libraries

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
myResultSet.getObject(                         // Use JDBC 4.2 or later to get *java.time* objects rather than mere strings.
    … ,                                        // Specify the column in database of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.
    Instant.class                              // Extract from database as a `Instant` object in UTC, via JDBC.
)
.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )         // Adjust into a time zone other than UTC. Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.toLocalDate()                                 // Extract the date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone. Returns a `LocalDate` object.
.atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )   // Determine the first moment of the day (not always 00:00). Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
```

And…

```
Duration.between( zdtStartOfDay , zdt )        // Represent the span of time between the first moment of the day and the target moment. Each argument is a `ZonedDateTime` object here.
    .toMillis()                                // Get entire span as a count of milliseconds. Returns a `long` primitive.
```

- No need for strings.
- No need for `java.sql.Timestamp`.

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy classes such as `java.sql.Timestamp` & `Date` & `Calendar`.

The [Answer by MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31715374/642706) is headed in the right direction by using *java.time* but uses the wrong class: `LocalDateTime` class purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC but our input string does. The `Z` on the end of the input String is short for `Zulu` and means UTC. Throwing away valuable information (zone/offset info) is not a good practice.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2015-07-24T09:39:14.000Z" ) ;
```

## Smart objects, not dumb strings

> I have to fetch time stamp from DB and retrieve only time and compare two time.
>
> below are the string values

Use appropriate objects to exchange data with your database, not mere strings.

As of JDBC 4.2, you can directly exchange *java.time* objects via `getObject` & `setObject`.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

You just fetched a date-time directly from a database column of type similar to the SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

For sending data to the database, use a `PreparedStatement` with placeholders.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

The `Instant` object retrieved via JDBC from the database is in UTC, by definition. To get the time-of-day, you must specify the wall-clock time of the region expected by the user (the time zone).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter pseudo-zones such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
```

Apply that time zone to get a `ZonedDateTime` object. The `Instant` and the `ZonedDateTime` represent **the same moment**, the same point on the timeline. This is a crucial concept to understand. Two friends talking on the phone, one in Québec Canada and one in Paris France will each look up to a clock on the wall simultaneously at the same moment yet see a different time in use by the people of their particular region.

```
ZoneDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

If you care only about the time-of-day, extract a `LocalTime` object.

```
LocalTime lt = zdt.toLocalTime();
```

Generate a `String` in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
String output = lt.toString();
```

Generate a string in localized format.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ;
String output = lt.format( f ) ;
```

But you seem to want a count of something since the start of the day – your Question is not clear. Perhaps you want a count of whole seconds, or milliseconds, or I don't know what.

We must get the start of the day in the desired/expected time zone. Do not assume the day starts at the time 00:00:00. Because of anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST), the day may start at another time such as 01:00:00. Let java.time determine the start of the day.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtStartOfDay = zdt.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Calculate the elapsed span of time as a `Duration`.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( zdtStartOfDay , zdt ) ;
```

Extract the entire span as a number of whole seconds.

```
long secondsSinceStartOfDay = d.toSeconds() ;
```

Extract the entire span as a number of milliseconds.

```
long millisSinceStartOfDay = d.toMillis() ;
```

Beware of data loss. The *java.time* classes have resolution of nanoseconds, so you are ignoring the finer parts of the value if present when you call the `to…` methods.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
        String date = "2015-07-24T09:39:14.000Z";
        //Now we are getting the time only from the above string.
        String time = date.substring(12, 19); 
        System.out.println("Time is: "+time);
        //Since we cannot convert symbols like":" to long we are removing them.
        String timeInLong = time.replaceAll(":", "");
        System.out.println("Time in long format : "+Long.parseLong(timeInLong));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with the next code, I use the library joda-time

`java.sql.Timestamp ts2 = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2015-07-24T09:45:44.000Z");`


`long dateLong=new DateTime(ts2).toDate().getTime();`